# Is there any alternative to IMPORTRANGE to cross update the sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I used the IMPORTRANGE but we cannot edit the data in another sheet where we fetched this. I found [this script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZtb3lRWn74) but same case here also.

Is there any method or script so we can import only a few columns and cross update them from both/any of these sheets?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a script which compared data in both the sheets and updates each sheets when change is there. To sync it perfectly, a trigger can be set for once in a day or as per your need so that sheets are synced. The code will include the logic to compare arrays as data of both the sheets.